# Creating a loop to check the column enteries in pandas

Tags: pandas, loops

Can anyone help me write a loop function for this use-case as I'm new to programming i don't get how to write this.

What i want is

A loop should check the the if the value of item_id column in the **DATAFRAME (B)** is same in the **question_id** column in the **DATAFRAME (questions)** , then it should compare user_answer entry **(Dataframe B)** to correct_answer **(Dataframe questions)** ,
if it matches then it should return **True/Correct or set a counter to +1**
if it doesn't match then it should return as **False/InCorrect or set a counter to -1**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
counter = 0
for key, item_id in B['item_id'].iteritems():
    try:
        if B.loc[key, 'user_answer'] == questions.loc[questions['question_id'] == item_id, 'correct_answer'].values[0]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            pass  # put here whatever you want to do if the answer is wrong
    except Exception:
        pass  # put here whatever you want to do if the question id from DF(B) is not in DF(questions)
```